# Ubuntu Server (18.04) screen resolution reset on boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Server on an Oracle VM VirtualBox. After boot the screen resolution is always 800x600 and I cannot change it.

I already tried all the suggested solutions I found in Internet but all of them are about changing grub configuration.

The strange thing here is: The grub configuration DOES work and the boot starts with the correct resolution. But during the process (all the init.d scripts are already running) it suddenly switches back to 800x600.

Is there any other thing I have to consider?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server).

Note that due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtin/+bug/1527664) changes to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` might be ignored. The issue is that `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg` overrides `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. If the curtin package is not installed on your system, you can simply remove `/etc/Default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg`. Otherwise, you will need to adjust the `50-curtin-settings.cfg`.

Comment: +1, still valid for Ubuntu 20.04 running as guest in KVM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following steps helped:

1. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions
2. Change Graphics Controller in Virtual Box settings:
   [Graphics Controller set to VMSVGA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMgbc.png)

After that screen resolution is automatically adapted to VM window which IMO is great feature.