# virtualbox guest display resolution reset to 800x600

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have installed the virtualbox 7.0.10 on host with windows 10 pro. Over virtualbox i am running the RockyLinux 9. The issue i have observed is that the display resolution of guest OS set to 800x600 every time i boot it, even after setting it to 1920x1080.

I have installed VirtualBox guest additions too and following are the logs showing it has been successfully installed.

> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Setting up modules
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions
> kernel
>
> modules.  This may take a while.
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed
> kernels, run
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
>
> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel
>
> 5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64.
>
> $ sudo cat vboxadd-setup.log
>
> Building the main Guest Additions 7.0.10 module for kernel
> 5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64.
>
> Building the shared folder support module.
>
> Building the graphics driver module.

I have also tried setting different graphics driver i.e. VBoxVGA, VBoxSVGA, VMSVGA, but no luck. I have also tried the VM setting "Visual State" to full screen and enabling the "Auto resize guest display" but I could not find any solution.

Comment: It seems like there are different approaches to set the desired screen resolution - check this, methods are shown there: https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/display-resolution-wont-stick/3148/11

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but this [article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server) found in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1378560/1874505) solved the issue for me with Ubuntu server.

In `/etc/default/grub`:

1. Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `nomodeset`
2. Set `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` to a resolution available in `videoinfo`

That should fix it after update&reboot.